# Why is MongoDB FindByIdAndUpdate giving me an error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I’m trying to update a MongoDB document with the code below. When I run it, I get the following error:

> error= MongoError: After applying the update to the document {_id:
>   ObjectId('596684d72084af52d51b4574') , ...}, the (immutable) field
>   '_id' was found to have been altered to _id:
>   ObjectId('596734cd9a40f6561bcd0c2a')

I can’t see for the life of me where I’m changing the _id field.

Can anyone see what I’m doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
exports.updateSubmission_post = function(req, res) {
    var submission = new Submission();
    submission.publication = req.body.sub_publication;
    submission.submission_date = req.body.sub_submission_date;
    submission.response_date = req.body.sub_response_date;
    submission.response = req.body.sub_response;
Submission.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.sub_submissionId, submission, {}, function (err, submission) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error= ' + err);
            return err;
        }else{
```

Comment: You are changing it in "`submission`" of course, where the `new` instance has a different `_id` value. Instead of throwing whole object at the server you should learn to just update the properties via [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a new document:

```
var submission = new Submission()
```

Mongoose will generate an `_id` for that document.

Next, you call `findByIdAndUpdate` with another `_id` (`req.body.sub_submissionId`), presumably from an *existing* document.

In other words, you're trying to update an existing document with a new document that has a different `_id`, which is why MongoDB returns the error (because you can't update/change `_id` values of documents already in the database).

Instead, you should pass an object with the fields you want to update:

```
var submission = {};
submission.publication = req.body.sub_publication;
submission.submission_date = req.body.sub_submission_date;
submission.response_date = req.body.sub_response_date;
submission.response = req.body.sub_response;
Submission.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.sub_submissionId, submission, ...)
```

That will (implicitly) call `$set` to update just those fields of the existing document in the database.

Comment: Thanks. That's sorted it.